# CakePHP : Explode POST request data

Tags: php, cakephp-2.1

I have a Javascript function that invoke a cakephp controller method:

```
$.ajax({   
     type: "POST",
     url: 'http://localhost/cakephp/officepersontasks/add',
     data: { 
         company_id: $("#company_id").val(), 
         person_id: $("#person_id").val(), 
         task_id: "11" 
     },
     success: function(data) {
         alert('Load was performed.'+data);
     }
});
```

On the cakeside, the object `$this->request->data` contain sended data, so `$this->OfficePersonTask->save($this->request->data)` will save data against `OfficePersonTask` model. The problem is that data sended got to be splitted, some data will be saved inside a DB table, the rest of data will be saved in a second table? What's the best solution to do this? How can I explode `$this->request->data` object?

Comment: are you looking for [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your form with cakes FormHelper like you would normally. You would then in the server-side code do a `saveAll` rather than a `save()` to save associated models as well.

Your javascript should then change to:

```
data: $('#myForm').serializeArray(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by splitting an object you meant putting part of the data of object in one array/object and other part in another. You can create a new array/object and populate it with parts of data that you require.

For an array you can do it as,

```
$new_data[] = $data->company_id;
$new_data[] = $data->person_id;
// now, $new_data has the values in an array.
```

You can do it easily for an object too.

Answer (score 0):

name your input fields with `data[modelName][fieldNameInTable]`.
When I say name i'm talking about the name field of inputs.
Then cake should save it directly!